# How to mark an option for install during burg install (non-graphical install)

Tags: package-management, installation, grub2

So when I tried installing Burg it came to a screen to select which device to install burg on. I highlighted SDA and hit enter and it just continued without installing it on that device. Is there another key I need to select to mark that option?

btw, I'm using the burg-manager to install it and when I try to emulate the burg menu it comes to this...

```
                    BURG version 1.98+20100623-1
```

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>

Comment: Well, I did get it installed correctly just from multiple attempts. I have run into this issue before though and would still like to know how to mark items during a non-graphical install. Another example of when I ran into this was installing ubuntu server edition. It gave options for ssh-server and such which I didn't select because enter just continued without selecting them. So does anyone know of the correct way to select an item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe hit Space ? That worked for me.

Comment: space worked. I got the chance to try it again finally

Answer (score 1):

For record purposes,this is the burg wiki page containing detailed instructions about how to install it on Ubuntu:
http://code.google.com/p/burg/wiki/InstallUbuntu

Comment: Yeah, I went there while trying to install burg. I got burg working, but still don't know how to mark an option for install during a non-graphical install.